# Microsoft Edge keeps freezing up

Tags: windows-10, browser, freeze, microsoft-edge

Reposting from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_crash-msedge_win10/edge-keeps-freezing-up/9bf6767f-c0d6-4c84-a0e6-d16d8ef11174):

> Last updated June 11, 2021
>
> My Microsoft Edge browser keeps freezing up. I have tried all the suggested solutions with no success. I like the design and functionality offered by Edge, but will change to Firefox until I get a notice that Microsoft has fixed the problem with Edge freeze ups.

Basically I'm experiencing exactly the same as him, and I'll take the exact same approach as him as well, just I don't have the account on answers.microsoft.com, so I'm hoping good folks will answer to this one once Microsoft has fixed the problem.

PS.

1. Today I got a push update to my Microsoft Edge, I have to start from setting up my profile. However the problem is getting much worse -- it'll hang right away when visiting our in-house MS TFS Git server, whereas previously it'll work at least for 10~20 minutes.
2. Sites I've been to before asking this question,

- https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftEdge/comments/knjc8l/microsoft_edge_freezing_pc/
- https://windowsreport.com/microsoft-edge-keeps-freezing-windows-10/
- https://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-edge-browser-hangs-freezes-windows-10

Comment: When mine freezes, maximizing another app, then coming back to Edge stop the freezing (until it freezes again).

Comment: Mine is actually not freeze, nor hang, just *anything* will load forever from our in-house MS TFS Git server. Any other sites still load instantaneously.

Answer (score -1):

If your [Microsoft Edge browser keeps Freezing](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-edge-browser-hangs-freezes-windows-10), hanging or crashing:

1. Set the Start page for browser and tabs to *about: blank*, disable feeds
2. Delete Edge browser cache, etc.
3. Disable or remove an incompatible extension

(You can get to know how to do that [HERE](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/microsoft-edge-browser-hangs-freezes-windows-10) )

4. Refresh/Modify Edge via Settings
5. Reset Edge via the browser
6. Disable Hardware Acceleration.

Comment: You should properly quote and cite your suggestion, just copying steps (without quoting) from a website, and providing doesn’t make an acceptable answer.